# Python array: formulas to populate array with data

Tags: python, arrays, array-formulas

I'd like like to populate an 24 x 4 array with data from formula(s).
Based on 4 initial values like so `[0, 0, 2137, 1419]` the array should be filled with numbers according to the output table below.

In Excel this is easy, when used from time to time. But when often used and with changing values in a,b,c or d it would most helpful to have Python create the various arrays.

Question: How can this be achieved in Python?

I'd assume nested `for i in j loops` might do the job, but honestly I am lost here. Help is highly appreciated.

**Initial-data:**

`a+` and `a-` use 7 rows

`b+` and `b-` use 5 rows

```
a = 0   b = 0   c = 2137  d = 1419
```

**Formulas:**
Upper half has ascending values and lower half has descending values.
There is a very logical order as the flow of x+=1, x=x, x-=1 and x=x is shifted among the columns.
**Important note:** each formula refers to its preceding value in the row above it.

```
a = 0   b = 0   c = 2137  d = 1419 

a+=1    b=b     c+=1      d=d           0
a+=1    b=b     c+=1      d=d           1
a+=1    b=b     c+=1      d=d           2
a+=1    b=b     c+=1      d=d           3
a+=1    b=b     c+=1      d=d           4
a+=1    b=b     c+=1      d=d           5
a+=1    b=b     c+=1      d=d           6 (7 for rows is known)
a=a     b+=1    c=c       d+=d        0
a=a     b+=1    c=c       d+=d        1
a=a     b+=1    c=c       d+=d        2
a=a     b+=1    c=c       d+=d        3
a=a     b+=1    c=c       d+=d        4   (5 for rows is known)
a-=a    b=b     c-=c      d=d           0
a-=a    b=b     c-=c      d=d           1
a-=a    b=b     c-=c      d=d           2
a-=a    b=b     c-=c      d=d           3
a-=a    b=b     c-=c      d=d           4
a-=a    b=b     c-=c      d=d           5
a-=a    b=b     c-=c      d=d           6 (7 for rows is known)
a=a     b-=b    c=c       d-=d        0
a=a     b-=b    c=c       d-=d        1
a=a     b-=b    c=c       d-=d        2
a=a     b-=b    c=c       d-=d        3
a=a     b-=b    c=c       d-=d        4   (5 for rows is known)
                                    Rows    
0       1       2         3         Columns
```

**Output:**

```
array = ([0,0,2137,1419],
[1,0,2138,1419],
[2,0,2139,1419],
[3,0,2140,1419],
[4,0,2141,1419],
[5,0,2142,1419],
[6,0,2143,1419],
[7,0,2144,1419],
[7,1,2144,1420],
[7,2,2144,1421],
[7,3,2144,1422],
[7,4,2144,1423],
[7,5,2144,1424],
[6,5,2143,1424],
[5,5,2142,1424],
[4,5,2141,1424],
[3,5,2140,1424],
[2,5,2139,1424],
[1,5,2138,1424],
[0,5,2137,1424],
[0,4,2137,1423],
[0,3,2137,1422],
[0,2,2137,1421],
[0,1,2137,1420],
[0,0,2137,1419])
```

Comment: Why don't `a-=a`, `b-=b`, `c-=c` and `d-=d` become 0? I think you mean `-=1` respectively. Also, do you have numpy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't reply to my comment yet. But looking at the desired output and the text after ***Formulas:*** I reckon, that you really meant to add/subtract 1 rather than the variables themselves.

So, you're basically repeatedly adding the vector `[1,0,1,0]` in the first 7 rows, then `[0,1,0,1]` in the next five and then subtracting again the same thing.
This is nicely linear, so you can sum them all up cumulatively and apply the results always to the first row. That is great for `numpy`!

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

# first 7 rows add 1 to a and 1 to c
add1 = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0])

# next 5 rows add 1 to b and 1 to d
add2 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1])

# stack them accordingly
upper = np.vstack(list(it.chain(it.repeat(add1, 7),
                                it.repeat(add2, 5))))

# lower is the negated version of upper
lower = -upper

# stack them
both = np.vstack((upper,
                  lower))

# with cumsum we'll get for each row the relative distance to the first row
# (istead of distance to previous)
sums = np.cumsum(both, axis=0)

# prepend 0 vector to retain the the first row
sums = np.vstack((np.zeros_like(add1), sums))

# create the frist row
l = np.array([0, 0, 2137, 1419])

# now just add up row and sums
result = l+sums

print(result)
```

That will be very fast, also for large arrays. If, however, you don't have numpy or don't want to install it, you can use some `zip` and `map` trickery to implement an equivalent approach.

```
import itertools as it

def addVecs(a, b):
    return [e1 + e2 for e1, e2 in zip(a, b)]


def scaleVec(a, s):
    return [e*s for e in a]


# first 7 rows add 1 to a and 1 to c
add1 = [1, 0, 1, 0]

# next 5 rows add 1 to b and 1 to d
add2 = [0, 1, 0, 1]

# stack them accordingly
upper = list(it.chain(it.repeat(add1, 7),
                      it.repeat(add2, 5)))

# lower is the negated version of upper
lower = list(it.starmap(scaleVec, zip(upper, it.repeat(-1))))

# stack them
both = upper + lower

# create cumsum to get for each row the relative distance to the first row
# (istead of distance to previous)
sums = [[0, 0, 0, 0]]
for row in both:
    sums.append(addVecs(sums[-1], row))

# the first row
l = [0, 0, 2137, 1419]

# now for each row in sums, add it to l
result2 = list(it.starmap(addVecs, zip(it.repeat(l), sums)))
for row in result2:
    print(row)
```

Both results contain your desired output:

```
[[   0    0 2137 1419]
 [   1    0 2138 1419]
 [   2    0 2139 1419]
 [   3    0 2140 1419]
 [   4    0 2141 1419]
 [   5    0 2142 1419]
 [   6    0 2143 1419]
 [   7    0 2144 1419]
 [   7    1 2144 1420]
 [   7    2 2144 1421]
 [   7    3 2144 1422]
 [   7    4 2144 1423]
 [   7    5 2144 1424]
 [   6    5 2143 1424]
 [   5    5 2142 1424]
 [   4    5 2141 1424]
 [   3    5 2140 1424]
 [   2    5 2139 1424]
 [   1    5 2138 1424]
 [   0    5 2137 1424]
 [   0    4 2137 1423]
 [   0    3 2137 1422]
 [   0    2 2137 1421]
 [   0    1 2137 1420]
 [   0    0 2137 1419]]
```

I tested the performance of both approaches on my laptop. Having `sums` already built up, `numpy` takes 6.29 µs and plain python 29.5 µs.

Comment: Great thank you! Your assumption was correct. In your numPy solution I had to remove 'list()' and the code worked perfectly. The plain Python solution then stops at 'both' when stacking the 'itertools.chain object' and 'itertools.starmap object'.

Comment: Interesting... I didn't know `vstack` accepts generators. Still, it should not be *necessary* to remove `list` from there. Which error did you get?  
And you should certainly leave `list` in the plain python version. As you noticed, without it, you end up with a `chain` object and a `starmap` object which both are generators. That's why I turned them into a list, you cannot add up generators and once they are consumed you cannot reiterate over them.

Comment: Well, I don't really know - I am a novice to Python. After consulting the manual for `np.vstack` I figured to change that line as follows and it worked: `upper = np.vstack(it.chain(it.repeat(add1, 7), it.repeat(add2, 5)))`. However it seems that this does not work for the pure Python solution. The `chain object` and a `starmap object` get stuck when they get stacked `both = upper + lower`. msg is: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'itertools.chain' and 'itertools.starmap'`. I am working in a jupyter notebook on a windows7-64 machine.

Comment: Forgot to provide the error msg in jupyter notebook: `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`. This msg appears when running both code options as posted. Full error-msg as follows: `TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-262-ddf137543cd7> in <module>()
     10 # stack them accordingly
     11 upper = np.vstack(list(it.chain(it.repeat(add1, 7),
---> 12                                 it.repeat(add2, 5))))
     13 
     14 # lower is the negated version of upper

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

Comment: That is probably because you named a list 'list'. You should try to avoid using names of built-in functions for your variables. They are highlighted green in jupyter ;)

Comment: Ahaaa, yes, 'list' was highlighted green. In essence, all my comments are obsolete - except to say, THANK YOU.